# App inventor 2-Showing multiple API results

Tags: api, google-api, app-inventor

The API results I am trying to access have multiple results. Right now I can only output one result of a name for example. Where am I going wrong? Any suggestions? I'm just looking for guidance.

My API results and test project:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/mitappinventortest/specific-programming-issue/9wfswNmhszo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert the JSON result into a list of lists, then loop through one of the inner lists, which provide your results. It also helps to use **Do it** to debug your blocks...

In the test I used a 3 element JSON result, therefore you get only 3 names in the result list.

[image]

Edit: solution to assign the result to different labels
[image]

Comment: If I wanted to output 1 result per Label#.text, would I change the index to 1 and ? Example output 3 results to Label1.text, Label2.text,Lablet3.text. What is the point of the index number?

Comment: Yes, you can do this, just use the advanced label blocks. However, you can't create components dynamically, you have to create as many labels as you may need before. See an example, which uses the advanced button blocks [here](https://puravidaapps.com/quiz.php)

Comment: From the example above, I am getting an error at runtime:Select list item: Attempt to get item number 4 of a list of length 3: (com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Label@431260a0 com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Label@43128b48 com.google.appinventor.components.runtime.Label@4312a948) --- WhenI select "Do it" I see that the select list item cannot accept argument. Which I believe would be the .JsonDevode jsonText. I'm going to try it a different way, but I just wanted to let you know.

Comment: yes, I did not add data validation. If you only have 3 labels, you will get an error if you try to assign the 4th value, just add an if statement: `if index <= length of list (list) then set label.Text ...`